# Table with caption too wide for standalone package document

Tags: tables, captions, standalone

I am trying to output a wide table with a caption using the `standalone` package.

When I do the following without a caption, I get nice output:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
%\minipage{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 3}
\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}
    \cmidrule(r){5-7}
    \cmidrule(r){8-10}
%
  Variable
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
\\
\midrule
  Brand1:$\log p_t$
    & -3.44 & 0.226 & 2e-16***
    & -3.39 & 0.227 & 2e-16***
    & -3.27 & 0.231 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_t$
    & -2.67 & 0.250 & 2e-16***
    & -2.62 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
    & -2.61 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_t$
    & -4.45 & 0.413 & 2e-16***
    & -4.50 & 0.425 & 2e-16***
    & -4.43 & 0.427 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_t$
    & -2.34 & 0.607 & 1e-4***
    & -2.32 & 0.601 & 1e-4***
    & -2.38 & 0.599 & 9e-5***
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_t$
    & -3.92 & 0.536 & 2e-12***
    & -3.90 & 0.532 & 2e-12***
    & -3.86 & 0.530 & 2e-12***
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.435 & 0.227 & 0.056.
    & 0.518 & 0.229 & 0.024*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.226 & 0.248 & 0.362
    & 0.256 & 0.248 & 0.302
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 1.024 & 0.410 & 0.012*
    & 1.078 & 0.423 & 0.011*
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.547 & 0.602 & 0.364
    & 0.543 & 0.598 & 0.364
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.151 & 0.532 & 0.777
    & 0.183 & 0.531 & 0.731
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.465 & 0.231 & 0.045*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.241 & 0.248 & 0.332
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.067 & 0.413 & 0.870
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & -0.508 & 0.599 & 0.397
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.047 & 0.530 & 0.979
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.146}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.131}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.114}
\\
  Brand2:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.109}
\\
  Brand3:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.108}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
  Brand4:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.194}
\\
  Brand5:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.110}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\captionof{table}{Regression results for 5 brands of coffee in a single store.}
%\endminipage
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code without caption]

Based on [Errors using standalone package to create a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93880/errors-using-standalone-package-to-create-a-table), I try to use a `minipage` environment and the `caption` package to include a caption.  The code and the output follows below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\minipage{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 3}
\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}
    \cmidrule(r){5-7}
    \cmidrule(r){8-10}
%
  Variable
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
    & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
\\
\midrule
  Brand1:$\log p_t$
    & -3.44 & 0.226 & 2e-16***
    & -3.39 & 0.227 & 2e-16***
    & -3.27 & 0.231 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_t$
    & -2.67 & 0.250 & 2e-16***
    & -2.62 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
    & -2.61 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_t$
    & -4.45 & 0.413 & 2e-16***
    & -4.50 & 0.425 & 2e-16***
    & -4.43 & 0.427 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_t$
    & -2.34 & 0.607 & 1e-4***
    & -2.32 & 0.601 & 1e-4***
    & -2.38 & 0.599 & 9e-5***
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_t$
    & -3.92 & 0.536 & 2e-12***
    & -3.90 & 0.532 & 2e-12***
    & -3.86 & 0.530 & 2e-12***
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.435 & 0.227 & 0.056.
    & 0.518 & 0.229 & 0.024*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.226 & 0.248 & 0.362
    & 0.256 & 0.248 & 0.302
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 1.024 & 0.410 & 0.012*
    & 1.078 & 0.423 & 0.011*
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.547 & 0.602 & 0.364
    & 0.543 & 0.598 & 0.364
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.151 & 0.532 & 0.777
    & 0.183 & 0.531 & 0.731
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.465 & 0.231 & 0.045*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.241 & 0.248 & 0.332
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.067 & 0.413 & 0.870
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & -0.508 & 0.599 & 0.397
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.047 & 0.530 & 0.979
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.146}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.131}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.114}
\\
  Brand2:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.109}
\\
  Brand3:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.108}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
  Brand4:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.194}
\\
  Brand5:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.110}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Regression results for 5 brands of coffee in a single store.}
\endminipage
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code with caption]

What should I do so that the output is not cut off?

Comment: Your table is too wide for `\textwidth`.  In the first case, it goes into the margin, but your viewer can still see it.  Inside the minipage, the extra gets truncated.  Set the minipage width to `1.7\textwidth` and you'll see the table reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the problem arises because TeX tries to use the same font size (viz., `\normalsize`) for the `tabular` environment and the caption material. Because you're using the fairly narrow default value of `\textwidth` and, moreover, are using only 90% of that amount for the minipage, the table is simply too wide to fit in the space available.

I suggest you do the following: (i) use narrower column headers, (ii) reduce the value of the `\tabcolsep` parameter (which governs the width of the intercolumn space), (iii) don't use any whitespace at the start and end of the table, as well as (iv) use the `dcolumn` pacakge to align the numbers in four of the six data columns on the decimal points. With these changes, you'll get a table that uses the same font size for the caption and the contents of the `tabular` environment -- and fits into the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcolumntype{z}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lzzlzzlzzl@{}}
\toprule
  Variable
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Model 3}
\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \cmidrule(l){8-10}
%
    & \mc{Coeff} & \mc{Std Err} & $p$-value
    & \mc{Coeff} & \mc{Std Err} & $p$-value
    & \mc{Coeff} & \mc{Std Err} & $p$-value\\
\midrule
  Brand1:$\log p_t$
    & -3.44 & 0.226 & 2e-16***
    & -3.39 & 0.227 & 2e-16***
    & -3.27 & 0.231 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_t$
    & -2.67 & 0.250 & 2e-16***
    & -2.62 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
    & -2.61 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_t$
    & -4.45 & 0.413 & 2e-16***
    & -4.50 & 0.425 & 2e-16***
    & -4.43 & 0.427 & 2e-16***
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_t$
    & -2.34 & 0.607 & 1e-4***
    & -2.32 & 0.601 & 1e-4***
    & -2.38 & 0.599 & 9e-5***
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_t$
    & -3.92 & 0.536 & 2e-12***
    & -3.90 & 0.532 & 2e-12***
    & -3.86 & 0.530 & 2e-12***
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.435 & 0.227 & 0.056.
    & 0.518 & 0.229 & 0.024*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.226 & 0.248 & 0.362
    & 0.256 & 0.248 & 0.302
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 1.024 & 0.410 & 0.012*
    & 1.078 & 0.423 & 0.011*
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.547 & 0.602 & 0.364
    & 0.543 & 0.598 & 0.364
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-1}$
    & & &
    & 0.151 & 0.532 & 0.777
    & 0.183 & 0.531 & 0.731
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.465 & 0.231 & 0.045*
\\
  Brand2:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.241 & 0.248 & 0.332
\\
  Brand3:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.067 & 0.413 & 0.870
\\
  Brand4:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & -0.508 & 0.599 & 0.397
\\
  Brand5:$\log p_{t-2}$
    & & &
    & & &
    & 0.047 & 0.530 & 0.979
\\[5pt]
  Brand1:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.146}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.131}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.114}
\\
  Brand2:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.109}
\\
  Brand3:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.108}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
  Brand4:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.194}
\\
  Brand5:MAPE
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.110}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Regression results for 5 brands of coffee in a single store.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for this example so I am accepting it. However, supposing that my table were really too wide, if it say had additional models, and it would not be possible to fit in the available space, is there a way to make the available space wider?

Comment: @ILiketoCode - thanks! If the table were even wider, one could proceed by choosing a smaller font size via a `\small` or `\footnotesize` instruction or via a `\resizebox` command. There are quite a few examples on TeX.SE of just such operations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it is not possible to use the `geometry` package or any other method to increase the width of the `standalone` document?

Comment: @ILiketoCode - It is definitely *possible* to use a package such as  `geometry` to define a very wide text block. An overriding issue is this: What do you want to convey to your reader(s)? The table above already contains ten columns; what are your readers supposed to take away from seeing a table that has, say, 16, 19, or 25 columns? Would they maybe be better off if you created two (or three, depending on how many models you have and need to report on) separate tables, each containing no more than ten columns?

Answer (score 3):

I would break this into two parts.

(1) I would put the table in its own file.

(2) I would import the table using `\includegraphics`

Call the file for your table `mytable.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 3}
    \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-4}
        \cmidrule(r){5-7}
        \cmidrule(r){8-10}
    %
      Variable
        & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
        & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
        & Coefficient & Std Error & $p$-value
    \\
    \midrule
      Brand1:$\log p_t$
        & -3.44 & 0.226 & 2e-16***
        & -3.39 & 0.227 & 2e-16***
        & -3.27 & 0.231 & 2e-16***
    \\
      Brand2:$\log p_t$
        & -2.67 & 0.250 & 2e-16***
        & -2.62 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
        & -2.61 & 0.248 & 2e-16***
    \\
      Brand3:$\log p_t$
        & -4.45 & 0.413 & 2e-16***
        & -4.50 & 0.425 & 2e-16***
        & -4.43 & 0.427 & 2e-16***
    \\
      Brand4:$\log p_t$
        & -2.34 & 0.607 & 1e-4***
        & -2.32 & 0.601 & 1e-4***
        & -2.38 & 0.599 & 9e-5***
    \\
      Brand5:$\log p_t$
        & -3.92 & 0.536 & 2e-12***
        & -3.90 & 0.532 & 2e-12***
        & -3.86 & 0.530 & 2e-12***
    \\[5pt]
      Brand1:$\log p_{t-1}$
        & & &
        & 0.435 & 0.227 & 0.056.
        & 0.518 & 0.229 & 0.024*
    \\
      Brand2:$\log p_{t-1}$
        & & &
        & 0.226 & 0.248 & 0.362
        & 0.256 & 0.248 & 0.302
    \\
      Brand3:$\log p_{t-1}$
        & & &
        & 1.024 & 0.410 & 0.012*
        & 1.078 & 0.423 & 0.011*
    \\
      Brand4:$\log p_{t-1}$
        & & &
        & 0.547 & 0.602 & 0.364
        & 0.543 & 0.598 & 0.364
    \\
      Brand5:$\log p_{t-1}$
        & & &
        & 0.151 & 0.532 & 0.777
        & 0.183 & 0.531 & 0.731
    \\[5pt]
      Brand1:$\log p_{t-2}$
        & & &
        & & &
        & 0.465 & 0.231 & 0.045*
    \\
      Brand2:$\log p_{t-2}$
        & & &
        & & &
        & 0.241 & 0.248 & 0.332
    \\
      Brand3:$\log p_{t-2}$
        & & &
        & & &
        & 0.067 & 0.413 & 0.870
    \\
      Brand4:$\log p_{t-2}$
        & & &
        & & &
        & -0.508 & 0.599 & 0.397
    \\
      Brand5:$\log p_{t-2}$
        & & &
        & & &
        & 0.047 & 0.530 & 0.979
    \\[5pt]
      Brand1:MAPE
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.146}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.131}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.114}
    \\
      Brand2:MAPE
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.111}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.109}
    \\
      Brand3:MAPE
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.108}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
    \\
      Brand4:MAPE
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.192}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.194}
    \\
      Brand5:MAPE
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.110}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.103}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.099}
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Then create another document from which to import the image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mytable}
\captionof{table}{Regression results for 5 brands of coffee in a single store.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]