# converting a table to png using standalone

Tags: tables, standalone, png

I am using `standalone` to convert a table to PNG. I have followed the following example. I got the output in PNG as well, please see the attached. However, when I view it with any of the image viewers (GIMP, IMAGEMAGICK etc), the background is not white. It has black and white square boxes. Surprisingly, here it is with white background. I will be very thankful if some one tell me the solution.

[I have followed the following example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93880/errors-using-standalone-package-to-create-a-table)

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
\hline
        Device & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 \\
        \hline
        Non-smarthphones & 22686 & 55813 & 108750 & 196262 & 357797 & 615679 \\
        Smarthphones & 104759 & 365550 & 933373 & 1915173 & 3257030 & 5221497 \\
        Laptops e Netbooks & 373831 & 612217 & 917486 & 1340062 & 1963950 & 2617770\\
        Tablets & 17393 & 63181 & 141153 & 300519 & 554326 & 1083895\\
        Home gateways & 55064 & 108073 & 180562 & 267545 & 376494 & 514777 \\
        M2M & 23009 & 47144 & 92150 & 172719 & 302279 & 508022 \\
        Altri devices & 525 & 1460 & 5429 & 22966 & 84204 & 242681\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the code]
[image: Screen shot of the GIMP]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The black and white squares should mean that the PNG has “transparent” background.

Comment: Thank you egreg for the reply. How can I change the background to white.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I call a hack; the `standalone` class should have a key for passing other options to `convert`.

```
\documentclass[
  convert={
    density=300 -alpha deactivate,
    size=1080x800,
    outext=.png
  },
]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
\hline
        Device & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 \\
        \hline
        Non-smarthphones & 22686 & 55813 & 108750 & 196262 & 357797 & 615679 \\
        Smarthphones & 104759 & 365550 & 933373 & 1915173 & 3257030 & 5221497 \\
        Laptops e Netbooks & 373831 & 612217 & 917486 & 1340062 & 1963950 & 2617770\\
        Tablets & 17393 & 63181 & 141153 & 300519 & 554326 & 1083895\\
        Home gateways & 55064 & 108073 & 180562 & 267545 & 376494 & 514777 \\
        M2M & 23009 & 47144 & 92150 & 172719 & 302279 & 508022 \\
        Altri devices & 525 & 1460 & 5429 & 22966 & 84204 & 242681\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. \documentclass[
  convert={
    density=300 -alpha deactivate -background white,
    size=1080x800,
    outext=.png
  },
]{standalone}

Comment: @egreg Neither the answer nor the answer with the additional "-background white" produce a white background—at least not with TeX Live 2015. The background remains transparent in both cases.

Comment: @Calaf I get white background. What OS are you on?

Comment: @egreg I'm on OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan).

Comment: @Calaf I'm too.

Comment: @egreg Interesting... Could ImageMagick be the culprit on my side? `convert --version` gives me: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-4 Q16 x86_64 2016-02-29.

Comment: @Calaf I have `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-13`

Comment: @egreg It got weirder after I upgraded. I asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317277/9549

Comment: For `ImageMagick 7.0.7-21 Q16 x64 2018-01-06` the only command that seems to work is `magick input.pdf -alpha remove output.png`.  The problem is that `-alpha` must be *between two files*, so appending it to density value (which comes *before the first file*) does not work.  There is a way to reconstruct the command that is sent by `standalone` (sub-option `command`, Pg. 17 in manual), which however does not work.

Comment: @Pygmalion I have ImageMagick 7.0.7-22 Q16; the command `convert -density 300 -alpha deactivate test.pdf test.png` works, and indeed the test above runs without problems.

Comment: Even with the newest version (`ImageMagick 7.0.7-22 Q16 x64 2018-01-22`) this command returns `no images found for operation '-alpha' at CLI arg 3 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/5266`

Comment: @Pygmalion It does for me, but I don't have Windows.

Comment: Oh well, then `imagemagick` is pain in the ass with its ever changing command parameters and incompatibility between different systems.

Comment: @Pygmalion It used to be even worse when GraphicsMagick had its own `convert` program; then I guess both teams realized that having `convert` was a nuisance, particularly on Windows that has its own too.

Comment: What if the table is in landscape mode and is also containing refs.