# standalone package: reconstruction of the command line

Tags: standalone

With current version of ImageMagick, `ImageMagick 7.0.7-21 Q16 x64 2018-01-06` application filename is long ago `magick` so the `standalone` package should be invoked by something like this:

```
\documentclass[convert={convertexe=magick,density=200,outext=.png}]{standalone}
```

which sends command

```
magick -density 200 filename.pdf filename.png
```

to the prompt.  Now this procedure results with PNGs with a transparent background.  To avoid transparence prompt command should be changed to

```
magick -density 200 filename.pdf -alpha remove filename.png
```

that is, `-alpha remove` should be put between two filenames.  This means that `-alpha remove` cannot be simply attacked to `density=200`, as proposed elsewhere: [converting a table to png using standalone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249261/converting-a-table-to-png-using-standalone).

I went through the `standalone` package, and Pg. 17 of the [manual](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) suggests that command prompt could be reconstructed using sub-option `command`.  So what I actually tried to do is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={convertexe=magick,density=200,outext=.png,command={\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space -alpha remove\space \outfile}}]{standalone}
```

However, it seems that command reconstruction does not work, as `PdfLatex` compiler from `Miktex` returns `! Undefined control sequence.` upon invoking `\convertexe`.

The example in the manual reads:

```
command={\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space -quality 90 \outfile}
```

What is wrong?  Did I misread the instructions?

Comment: Opened a ticket: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/37/standaloneconfig-doesnt-work-for-setting

Comment: @egreg What about putting command specification in `[]` brackets?  Would that qualify as a bug or as me misreading the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have the following `test.tex` file

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

along with the following `standalone.cfg` file in the same directory

```
\standaloneconfig{
  multi=false,
  crop,
  convert={
    convertexe=magick,
    density=200,
    outext=.png,
    command={%
      \convertexe\space
      -density \density\space
      \infile\space
      -alpha remove\space
      \outfile
    }
  }
}
```

then running

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

results in calling the external program

```
magick -density 200 test.pdf -alpha remove test.png
```

as can be seen in the `test.log` file by looking for `runsys`. Indeed, if I ask for information about the file, I get

```
> file test.png
test.png: PNG image data, 1700 x 2200, 4-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```

### Update

You can specify the commands also in the options, but with a small tweak:

```
\documentclass[
  tikz,
  multi=false,
  crop,
  convert={
    convertexe=magick,
    density=200,
    outext=.png,
    command=\unexpanded{%
      \convertexe\space
      -density \density\space
      \infile\space
      -alpha remove\space
      \outfile
    },
  },
]{standalone}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the log file I find

```
runsystem(magick -density 200 conv.pdf -alpha remove conv.png)...executed.
```

and the generated file reports

```
> identify test.png
test.png PNG 159x80 159x80+0+0 8-bit Gray 16c 900B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: @Pygmalion Add `crop` to the options, see the edit

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  But it is the bug that this does not work in `[]` brackets?  The specification with brackets would be much more flexible.  If so, I'll keep the question open, maybe author will fix the bug.

Comment: @Pygmalion If it is a bug, you'd be better off contacting the author directly. Not all authors haunt TeX SE.

Comment: @cfr Well, the author is a moderator of this site. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Couldn't remember who wrote it. But it is still reasonable advice as a general policy. And even moderators don't actually live here. For a terrible moment, though, I thought you meant an author of something else. So glad you did not.

Comment: @cfr See comment to the question