# How can I implement any runsystem command in a .Tex file?

Tags: standalone, convert, pdftops

I have the following tex file:

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}

\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\small}l >{\small}r >{\small}r >{\small}r >{\small}r} 
    \toprule
    Gas & $\sigma / \text{\AA}$ & $\sfrac{\varepsilon}{\kappa} /  \text{K} $ & $\sfrac{\kappa T}{\varepsilon}$ / \text{-} & $\Omega_ \mu / \text{-} $ \\
    \midrule
    H\textsubscript{2} & $2.915$ & $ 38$ & $7.77$ & $0.86$ \\
    N\textsubscript{2} & $3.667$ & $100$ & $2.96$ & $1.04$ \\
    O\textsubscript{2} & $3.433$ & $113$ & $2.61$ & $1.08$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Whenever I run it, I read in the log file the following:

> runsystem(imgconvert -density 300 Table_1.pdf  -quality 90
>   Table_1.png)...executed.

What I guess happened during compilation is that the command "imgconvert etc etc" was ran on Windows to convert the pdf to a png.

What I would like to do now is add a command in my tex file that outputs:

> runsystem(pdftops -eps Table_1.pdf Table_1.eps)...executed.

Here's how standalone implements it:

```
\sa@convertoption{imagemagick}[]{%
\def\sa@convert@command{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space -quality 90 \outfile}%
\let\sa@convert@pageoffset\m@ne
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've found a workaround in the `standalone` package that can be implemented in one of two ways:

- Modify the `standalone.cls` file between lines 394 and 395 to include the following:

  ```
  \sa@convertoption{eps}[]{%
      \def\sa@convert@command{pdftops\space -eps\space \infile\space\outfile}%
      \sa@convertvar{outext}{.eps}
  }
  ```

and then make the document class look like `\documentclass[convert=eps]{standalone}`.

- Modify the document class line to look like

  ```
  \documentclass[convert={command=\unexpanded{pdftops\space -eps\space \jobname.pdf\space \jobname.eps},imagemagick}]{standalone}
  ```

My issue now is that I want `standalone` to convert the PDF file to both PNG and EPS but I think that `standalone` was made to do only one conversion. The only solution to this is to run the file twice, once with `convert=eps` and once with `convert=imagemagick`.

Comment: You are on the right track. If you compile using command line, you can write a script that will first do the conversion (assuming you know the image names), then proceed to process your tex file. In other words, you would do the conversion outside of TeX.

Comment: Is there a way to run the complete file twice? Once with convert=imagemagick and once with convert=eps. The pdf will be rewritten but it produces the same image so there shouldn't be any problem. @RobtAll

Comment: Probably yes, using batch (shell) script. Outside my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413764/4427

```
\documentclass[
  convert={
    convertexe=pdftops -eps,
    outext=.eps,
    command=\unexpanded{%
      \convertexe\space
      \infile\space
      \outfile
    },
  }
]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{ lrrrr }
    \toprule
    Gas & $\sigma / \text{\AA}$ & $\sfrac{\varepsilon}{\kappa} /  \text{K} $ & $\sfrac{\kappa T}{\varepsilon}$ / \text{-} & $\Omega_ \mu / \text{-} $ \\
    \midrule
    H\textsubscript{2} & $2.915$ & $ 38$ & $7.77$ & $0.86$ \\
    N\textsubscript{2} & $3.667$ & $100$ & $2.96$ & $1.04$ \\
    O\textsubscript{2} & $3.433$ & $113$ & $2.61$ & $1.08$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of figured that out on my own but it's better the way you wrote it.